# "AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map" while installing jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

How do I resolve the following error while installing jupyter notebook on Ubuntu:

```
$pip3 install jupyter
```

**Errors**

1. `AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map`
2. `ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'widgetsnbextension ~=3.5.0', 'at', ' ~=3.5.0')`

```
        pratikubuntu@ubuntu-inspiron-3541:~$ pip3 install jupyter
    Downloading/unpacking jupyter
      Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Downloading/unpacking qtconsole (from jupyter)
      Downloading qtconsole-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121kB): 121kB downloaded
    Downloading/unpacking ipywidgets (from jupyter)
      Downloading ipywidgets-7.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121kB): 121kB downloaded
    Cleaning up...
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2482, in _dep_map
        return self.__dep_map
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2344, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
        requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
        req_to_install.extras):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2291, in requires
        dm = self._dep_map
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2484, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2508, in _compute_dependencies
        parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
        line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
        raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
    ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'widgetsnbextension ~=3.5.0', 'at', ' ~=3.5.0')

    Storing debug log for failure in /home/pratikubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: I am also experiencing this, did you ever find a solution?